# Given $n \in Z$ and $x \in Q$, find smallest $m \in Z$ such that $m>n$ and $x \times m \in Z$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an integer $n$ and a rational $x$ (we may assume that $|x|<1$ if it helps), find the smallest integer $m$ sun that $m>n$ and $x\times m$ is an integer.

I know (or at least believe that I do) how to find the smallest such integer: if $x = \frac{a}{10^b}$, then if $m = 10^{-b} \mathrm {lcm}(10^b,a) < a$ then $m$ is the smallest integer. But I need smallest greater than $n$.

**Add 1**

After the comment from Ross Millikan, it seems that if one represents $x = \frac{q}{p}$ in lowest terms, then the smallest integer $m > n$ is $m = p \times \lceil n/p\rceil {}$.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Thank you for your comment. I think I should be able to go from here.

Comment: Title has $n>m$, question has $m>n$, please resolve. (probably title is wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent $x$ as $\frac ab$, where $a,b\in \Bbb Z$, $b>0$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ - that is, $\frac ab $ is $x$ in its lowest terms.

Then with  $c:= mx$ and $c\in \Bbb Z$, we have $c=\frac{ma}b$, so $b\mid ma$ and since $a$ and $b$ have no factors in common, we must have $b\mid m$.

So we need $m = kb$, and we can determine the smallest $k$ (and hence the smallest $m$) that gives $m>n$ by taking $n/b$ and increasing to the next integer, so taking $k=\left\lceil \frac {n+1}b \right\rceil$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You seem to propose the same approach as shown in the first addendum in my post which was inspired by the comment of Ross Millikan. The only thing which seems to be different is that you suggest to use $n+1$ rather than $n$ in the numerator of the ceiling function.

Comment: Yes, just to get $m>n$ rather than $m\ge n$ in the case $b\mid n$.  Also using $p$ and $q$ in your note suggests to me that the parts of the fraction are primes, which obviously need not be so.